# Restoring svn backup (bzip2)

Tags: backup, compression

I have successfully made backup of my [SVN repository](https://www.projecthut.com/what-is-svn-repository/) as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/96224/is-it-safe-to-zip-tar-hotcopied-svn-repositories). However, how does one *restores* backed-up `repository`, i.e. initiate reverse operation of restoring backup, because after command:
`svnadmin dump /opt/repositories/TestRepo | bzip2 >> bckRepo_Test.bz2` file `ueBckRepo_Test.bz2` is created. After `bunzip2`-ing it, I simply get file `ueBckRepoTest` in current dir, how do I then *extract* svn repository (dir structure with **ALL FILES** in it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to finish the task:

1. Create new `repository` using [svnadmin create](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html) command
2. *Extract* compressed file contents using
   `bzip2 -dc repoBackup.bz2 | svnadmin load /path/to/newly_created_repository`

Comment: Is it possible to execute this commands on Synology Diskstation NASes?

Answer (score 1):

To import the dump file, make sure it’s an existing repository. If the repository is unavailable, use svnadmin create /path/to/repository as you noted above.

But note, you don’t have to import the dump file in the same SVN repository path. Use the following command:

```
svnadmin load /path/to/repository < svnexport.dump
```